# In Acrobat, can I make fields in an array required, or quickly make many fields required/not required?

Tags: javascript, acrobat

The lab I work in distributes and evaluates a proficiency test once a year, and is currently developing a PDF in Adobe Acrobat so we can collect the results digitally (rather than by mail). I'm completely new to JavaScript and its use in Acrobat, but have so far managed to cobble together a working form from awesome forum answers!

In the form, there are multiple tests, and each test may have multiple methods of performing the test. To make sure every field gets filled out, we've included coding based on radio button or drop-down selection.

```
var CDA = getField("CDA").value

var CDA1 = getField("CDA Unheated Sample 15");
var CDA2 = getField("CDA Unheated Sample 16");
var CDA3 = getField("CDA Unheated Sample 17");
var CDA4 = getField("CDA Unheated Sample 18");
var CDA5 = getField("CDA Unheated Sample 19");
var CDA6 = getField("CDA Unheated Sample 20");
var CDA7 = getField("CDA Unheated Sample 21");
var CDA8 = getField("CDA Unheated Sample 22");
var CDA9 = getField("CDA Unheated Positive Control");
var CDA10 = getField("CDA Unheated Negative Control");
var CDA11 = getField("CDA Interp Sample 15");
var CDA12 = getField("CDA Interp Sample 16");
var CDA13 = getField("CDA Interp Sample 17");
var CDA14 = getField("CDA Interp Sample 18");
var CDA15 = getField("CDA Interp Sample 19");
var CDA16 = getField("CDA Interp Sample 20");
var CDA17 = getField("CDA Interp Sample 21");
var CDA18 = getField("CDA Interp Sample 22");
var CDA19 = getField("CDA Interp Positive Control");
var CDA20 = getField("CDA Interp Negative Control");
var CDA21 = getField("Date Analyzed_2");
var CDA22 = getField("Sample temperature_3");

if ( CDA == "Not Performed") {
CDA1.required = false;
CDA2.required = false;
CDA3.required = false;
CDA4.required = false;
CDA5.required = false;
CDA6.required = false;
CDA7.required = false;
CDA8.required = false;
CDA9.required = false;
CDA10.required = false;
CDA11.required = false;
CDA12.required = false;
CDA13.required = false;
CDA14.required = false;
CDA15.required = false;
CDA16.required = false;
CDA17.required = false;
CDA18.required = false;
CDA19.required = false;
CDA20.required = false;
CDA21.required = false;
CDA22.required = false;
}

else if (CDA == "Performed") {
CDA1.required = true;
CDA2.required = true;
CDA3.required = true;
CDA4.required = true;
CDA5.required = true;
CDA6.required = true;
CDA7.required = true;
CDA8.required = true;
CDA9.required = true;
CDA10.required = true;
CDA11.required = true;
CDA12.required = true;
CDA13.required = true;
CDA14.required = true;
CDA15.required = true;
CDA16.required = true;
CDA17.required = true;
CDA18.required = true;
CDA19.required = true;
CDA20.required = true;
CDA21.required = true;
CDA22.required = true;
}
```

While the above works, it's feels pretty clunky, and is one of the shorter bits of code for a Performed/Not Performed method. For some of the tests with multiple methods, I have 3-5 conditions occurring that requires changing all of the 'required' fields every time (trying to idiot-proof it).

Is there a more efficient way to  change the 'required' status of a lot of fields at once? Could I store all the fields I might need to call on in an array, and then quickly change the 'required' status of all the fields in the array? Something more like:

```
var CDA = getField("CDA").value

var CDA_array = [getField("CDA Unheated Sample 15"),
getField("CDA Unheated Sample 16"),
getField("CDA Unheated Sample 17"),
getField("CDA Unheated Sample 18"),
getField("CDA Unheated Sample 19"),
getField("CDA Unheated Sample 20"),
getField("CDA Unheated Sample 21"),
getField("CDA Unheated Sample 22"),
getField("CDA Unheated Positive Control"),
getField("CDA Unheated Negative Control"),
getField("CDA Interp Sample 15"),
getField("CDA Interp Sample 16"),
getField("CDA Interp Sample 17"),
getField("CDA Interp Sample 18"),
getField("CDA Interp Sample 19"),
getField("CDA Interp Sample 20"),
getField("CDA Interp Sample 21"),
getField("CDA Interp Sample 22"),
getField("CDA Interp Positive Control"),
getField("CDA Interp Negative Control"),
getField("Date Analyzed_2"),
getField("Sample temperature_3")];

if (CDA == "Not Performed") {
CDA_array.required = false;
}

else if (CDA == "Performed") {
CDA_array.required = true;
}
```

Is this something that can be done, or should I just accept our first working version? I'm currently remote and can't access our workstation with a full Acrobat licence until next week, so I haven't been able to try the second block of code to see what happens. Thanks in advance for reading this big old novel, and any help or insight you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rename your fields to be hierarchical with dot notation, you can set the required property on the parent. Name your fields like this...

CDA.Unheated Sample 15

CDA.Unheated Sample 16

CDA.Unheated Sample 17

CDA.Interp Positive Control

etc...

Your code then becomes...

```
this.getField("CDA").required = true;
```

or

```
this.getField("CDA").required = false;
```

CDA is the parent field. The children then inherit the required property.

Comment: Thanks! If I name my fields say CDA.Sample.15 etc, to CDA.Control.Positive what would be the proper way to change just the fields in the control branch? Or calling a specific sub-level(?) under CDA. Would it be:
`this.getField("CDA.Control").required = true;`
or would
`this.getField("Control").required = true;`
be enough?

Comment: this.getField("CDA.Control").required = true;